Was Yzma supposed to say "Is that my voice?" twice?
At the end of The Emperor's New Groove, Yzma is turned into a cat. After hearing the high-pitched tone of her own voice, she says "Is that my voice? Is that my voice?"
This reminds me of a mistake I sometimes find in audio books, where the narrator does two takes of a particular line, intending for one take to be removed during editing, but the editor misses this and leaves both takes in the book. I'm wondering if something similar could have happened with Emperor's New Groove - was the line in the script twice, or did Eartha Kitt originally do two takes with different inflection, but the director decided to keep and animate both takes?

This is a film that famously didn't even have a written script until after they'd finished recording lines.

Presumably the first one is said because she can't believe this has happened, and the second because she can't believe this has happened to her.
